# How to incorporate storyboards into a cocos2d 2.0 and travel from one to the other?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking for help in trying to leave cocos2d back into main storyboard.

I have built a small app with storyboard that can lead into a game scene following fidgetware's tutorial ( How to incorporate storyboards into a cocos2d 2.0 project? ).

I have created a button in cocos2d using menu item with CClabelTTF and have provided a switch scene means as a way to go back into my mainstoryboard, I have declared the "page" in the cocos2d via #import in the top of file but I am not getting there every time I run and build.

my switch scene means in the cocos2d page:

```
(void)switchScene2
{
    CCTransitionFlipY *transition = [CCTransitionFlipY transitionWithDuration:2.0 scene:[trial node]];

    //Tell the director to replace the currently running scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];
}
```

any help would be appreciated and thanking in advance....

for iOS...thanks

good to read....no i meant not from coco to coco but from coco to Xcode...i must admit i don't understand "dismiss the view controller"....looking forward to your tutorial....thank you...

Comment: is your app for iOS or OSX?

Comment: I'll post a tutorial about cocos2d+storyboards in a couple hours (http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/blog). You need to dismissViewController if your segue is modal to return to the previous storyboard. If you meant to segue from one cocos2d view to another cocos2d view, you can't, use scene transitions.

Comment: The article is now live, hope it helps: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/05/cocos2d-v21-storyboards-done-right/

Comment: thank you Steffen for your timely tutorial....am working on it but am not sure i will succeed as there are things i think i still don't understand....(got both your books by the way and a regular  visitor to your site) cheers and thank you...